# perl extract common elements from 2 arrays (common sequences in fastq file)

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics, sequences, fastq

I have 2 file (paired_end) with reads in fastq format from the same organism (File_R1.fastq and File_R2.fastq). And I want to determinate the coverage deep using bwa and samtools (bioinformatics), for do it I need both files with the same number of reads, the same name (file_1: @XX00341:4450:6341 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT   and   file_2: @XX00341:4450:6341 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT), in the same order in both files, the problem is that both files have empty reads (The corresponding read for each file, could be empty in one but not in other !!!!), and if I try to run it with bwa it fails due to empty sequences.

So I'm trying to make a perl script to extract the NO empty reads with the same name and order in both files.

this is the format of fastq file (each read has 4 lines: name (@XX00341:19:000H27K25:1:11101:4450:6341 1:N....), sequence (GAGGTGCGTGGTTGTCACCCC...), Q_head (+) and Quality (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF....), in that order.

file_r1.fastq (characterized with = .... 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT)

```
@XX00341:4450:6341 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
CGCCCATCATGAGGTGCGTGGTTGTCACCCCCGCAAACGCGGAGGTGTAAACAGGCTCACCTGTGGGTTGTTGGTAGTCGTTATTGTGCTTGCGCTGTTCATCTGGATTACTGGATTCGACGCGTTGAGC
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@XX00341:14420:6341 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
GCTTTGTCGTCGTCGGTTTTAAAGTGAACCGCTTTACCTGTTTCTGCTTGAACTTGTTCTGCTTGAGGTGCTGCTTCTGGTTTTGTTTCTTCTTTCTGACAACCTACCGCTAGCATTACTGTTGCAGCAA
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/FFFFAAFFFFFFAFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFAFAFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFAFFFFFFF/FFFFFFFFFFFF
@XX00341:10259:6342 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT

+

@XX00341:6685:6342 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
CATTGGAAGGCAAGCCAGAACAAGGCAAGAATATTCCAGATGACATCGTGCGCGTTCGCATCGATCGCAACAGCGGTCTGCTGACTCATAAAGTGGATAGCACGTCCATGTTTGAATACTTTGAGAAAGG
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF6FFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@XX00341:4051:6343 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
TCACCATGATCGGATTTATGAATGGTTTAGTGGACAGCATGATCAAAAATGCGATTGCTTGGCAAACCAGCCATTTGCAGATTCATCAAAGTGCTTATCTCGTTAATCCTGAACTGAAAGACACCATACC
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@XX00341:12307:6344 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
TCCAAATTGAGAGTTAATGTGAAAAAAGAATGACTTTTTGCTTGTCATGCAGCGGATTTGTGTGATACCACTAATGACGCAAACATTTTCGTAGAACATTACACAATACTATTTAACGAAAAAAGAACGA
+
FAAFFAFAAFFAFFF/FF/FFAFFFFFFFFFAAFFF=F=AFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFAAFFFFFFFFFF/FAFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAFFAF///FAFFFFFF
@XX00341:24250:6345 1:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
CGAACATAGAGCAAGCTCTGGTAAGTCCCGATGGGAGCTTAAAGACACAAGTAGACCAAAAGCTCGCAGAACATGGCTTGAGCCGTAAAGTCACCGTGGCGTCGCGCAACTTTCTCACCATTCGGCATCT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

file_r2.fastq (characterized with = .... 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT)

```
@XX00341:4450:6341 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
GCGGCTTTGGTAGCGAAGCGCGTCTACCAACCGCAGCCATGAAACAACTGGCGTTTGAAGTGGAAAAAACGGCAGCGGGCAGTATTCCGGTACTGATTGAAGCCATCGAACAAGTGGCGGTGCCTACCGC
+
AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFF/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@XX00341:14420:6341 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
GCGGTTCGAGTGGCCAACGTTGAACTTCATGCTCGGTAAAAAAGCAACCATTTAACGTGGTGATGACAATTAAATATAGGAATAAATGAGAAATTCTTTGCATCACATCTAATAATCCGGTTTGTGTCTT
+
AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/FFFAFAFFFFFFFF/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFF
@XX00341:10259:6342 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
TCTTTTTTCGTTAAATAGTATTGTGTAAT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@XX00341:6685:6342 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
GAATAAATGCTGTCTTCGAGGCTGTTACCAACGTATTCGGTTGGCTCCGTGCCTTTCTCAAAGTATTCAAACATGGACGTGCTATCCACTTTATGAGTCAGCAGACCGCTGTTGCGATCGATGCGAACGC
+
AFFFFFFFFAFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/FF/FFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFF=FF=FFFFFFFAFFFFFFF
@XX00341:4051:6343 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
GAAGCTATCATGCCATCGGCGAGAAACCGCTCCGATACGGCTTTCACGCTTTGATGCTTGTCTAACGTTGTCACGATGCTTTGCGAGTCAGGTATGGTGTCTTTCAGTTCAGGATTAACGAGATAAGCAC
+
AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@XX00341:12307:6344 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
GTTCATCTGTCTGTCGTTCTTTTTTCGTTAAATAGTATTGTGTAATGTTCTACGAAAATGTTTGCGTCATTAGTGGTATCACACAAATCCGCTGCATGACAAGCAAAAAGTCATTCTTTTTTCACATTAA
+
AFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF=FFFFFFFAFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFF=FAFFFFFFFFAFFFAFFAFFFFFFFFA=AFF6AFFAFAFF
@XX00341:24250:6345 2:N:0:AACGTTAA+TTGCAATT
CCATAGCATGGCAATATCAAAATCCGCAACGGCGATCGGCGGCTTAACAGTAATGAGATCGTCTGAAAAGCCCTCCGCCAACGCCATTTTTTCTGGCACGATGGCAATGAGATCGCGCTTTTTCAATAGA
+
AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

in this case, one read is empty in the file_1.fastq (@XX00341:10259:6342 1:N....), the second and fourth line are empty (sequence and quality), but not in the file_2.fastq (@XX00341:10259:6342 2:N....); in this example both sequences (the 4 lines in each file) must be omited !!!

This is the code that I´m trying to finish:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($fastQ_R1, $fastQ_R2);
      GetOptions (
            'R1|r1=s'   =>\$fastQ_R1,
            'R2|r2=s'   =>\$fastQ_R2,

      );

    sub extract_list {
        my ($file_in) = @_;
        open FILE, '<', $file_in or die "cant open the $file_in\n";

        my (@elements, @list, @seq);
        while(
            defined(my $head    =   <FILE>) &&   # 1 line
            defined(my $seq     =   <FILE>) &&   # 2 line
            defined(my $qhead   =   <FILE>) &&   # 3 line
            defined(my $quality =   <FILE>)      # 4 line
        ){
            if ($seq=~ m/^$/g){
                next;
            }
            else {  push @seq, $head;   }
         }
        close FILE;
        foreach (@seq){
            chomp;
            @elements = split '\s', $_;
                push @list, $elements[0]; # split to eliminate 1:N... (file_1) and 2:N... (file_2)
        }
        return @list;
    }

    my @list_R1 = extract_list ($fastQ_R1);

    my @list_R2 = extract_list  ($fastQ_R2);
```

So far I have the list of No empty sequences (@list_R1 and @list_R2) in both files, the comparison the both arrays will give the No empty reads (with 4 lines !!) that are present in both files (@common_elements) obtained from the comparison of both array.

@list_R2=

```
@XX00341:4450:6341   
@XX00341:14420:6341   
@XX00341:6685:6342   
@XX00341:4051:6343   
@XX00341:12307:6344   
@XX00341:24250:6345
```

@list_R2=

```
@XX00341:4450:6341   
@XX00341:14420:6341   
@XX00341:10259:6342
@XX00341:6685:6342   
@XX00341:4051:6343   
@XX00341:12307:6344   
@XX00341:24250:6345
```

@common_elemnts=

```
@XX00341:4450:6341   
@XX00341:14420:6341   
@XX00341:6685:6342   
@XX00341:4051:6343   
@XX00341:12307:6344   
@XX00341:24250:6345
```

so the new array (@common_elemnts) will be used to search and extract the common reads (4 lines) foreach file and will give tow output files: Files_R1_common.fastq (obtained from the File_R1.fastq) and File_R2_common.fastq (obtained from the File_R2.fastq).

Any suggestion, will be appreciated !!!! 
Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use hash maps to check for item existence in lists.
Construct common hash map:

```
my %list1_map = map { $_, 1 } @list_R1;
my %common_map = map { $list1_map{$_} ? ($_, 1) : () )} @list_R2;
```

Then process your lists:

```
for my $item(@list_R1) {
if (defined ($common_map{$item})) {
    # ... process ...       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution, I've moved the FASTQ parsing to a separate class, which will read 4 lines from the file and return a hashref of id, hdr, seq, and qual representing one record.  I've left writing this class to you as an exercise.  Doing so makes the logic below easy to follow.  Readability is important.

This code simply saves the IDs (i.e. the $1 in $hdr=~/^@(\S+)/) of empty seqs from file1.  Then it reads file2 and outputs complete records and also saves IDs of empty records.  Finally, you read file1 again and output the complete records by removing those indicated by the %filtered hash.

This solution is inefficient in that it reads file1 twice.  Not mentioned in the original question was that FASTQ files typically contain millions of records, so saving all the unfiltered records from file1 in the %filtered hash would require a lot of RAM but if you have a lot of RAM, you could alter to suit, but personally I wouldn't worry about reading the file twice.

```
# SAVE IDS OF EMPTY RECORDS FROM FILE1 IN HASH
my %filter;
my $fq = new Fastq($file1);
while (my $rec = nextSeq($fq))
{
    $rec->{seq} or $filter{$rec->{id}} = undef; # not using value
}

# ADD IDS OF EMPTY RECORDS FROM FILE2 TO HASH AND OUTPUT FILTERED_FILE2
open(my $out, '>', "$file2.filtered") or die($!);
$fq = new Fastq($file2);
while (my $rec = nextSeq($fq) )
{
    if ( $rec->{seq} )
    {
        # READ2 FOR THIS PAIR IS NOT EMPTY
        if ( ! exists($filter{$rec->{id}}) )
        {
             # READ1 FOR THIS PAIR IS ALSO NOT EMPTY
             print $out join("\n", $rec->{hdr}, $rec->{seq}, '+', $rec->{qual}), "\n";
        }
    } else
    {
         # READ2 IS EMPTY, ADD TO FILTERED HASH
         $filtered{$rec->{id}} = undef;
    }
}
close($out);

# OUTPUT FILTERED_FILE1
open($out, '>', "$file1.filtered") or die($!);
$fq = new Fastq($file1);
while (my $rec = nextSeq($fq) )
{
    if ( $rec->{seq} and ! exists($filter{$rec->{id}}) )
    {
         print $out join("\n", $rec->{hdr}, $rec->{seq}, '+', $rec->{qual}), "\n";
    }
}  
close($out);
```